# Python beginner (dtale add on)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

first things first: I am completely new to Python - I am studying Geography and for a course work I want to do a statistical analysis of party manifesto mass data. I had one class with R but it's been a few semesters since then. So long story short, I hope there are no "bad" questions (as they always say ;) and that you can help me!

I am using the (relatively new) add-on dtale, as it requires not that much background in coding. I installed dtale in Visual Studio Code. So far, I am getting along quite well, but my commands only work via Terminal. My goal is to have a "documentary" of the coding process in the editor and when I press "run python file in editor" it should bring me to my status quo.

First question: Is this even possible?

Second question:

My code so far looks like this:

```
import dtale
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('https://mydata.csv')
d = dtale.show(df)
d.open_browser()
```

I usually type this code straight into the terminal using `/usr/bin/env python3`. Dtale already provided following snippets (I need to customize and filter etc.):

```
df.loc[:, 'edate'] = pd.Series(pd.to_datetime(df['edate'], infer_datetime_format=True), name='edate', index=df['edate'].index)
df = df.query("""`edate` >= '20140914' and `edate` <= '20200830'""")
```

Is it somehow possible to integrate this code into the editor, so that it executes the given code automatically when I press "run in Terminal"? I already tried it but errors occur:

```
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known>
```

Thanks a lot for your help and please excuse my beginner questions!

Best regards

Edit:

```py
import dtale
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('https://manifestoproject.wzb.eu/down/data/2020b/datasets/MPDataset_MPDS2020b.csv')
d = dtale.show(df)
d.open_browser()

df.loc[:, 'edate'] = pd.Series(pd.to_datetime(df['edate'], infer_datetime_format=True), name='edate', index=df['edate'].index)

df = df.query("""`edate` >= '20140914' and `edate` <= '20200830'""")
```

Edit2: Here is all information from Terminal:

```
source /Users/Lorenz_1/Library/r-miniconda/bin/activate
Lorenz@Lorenzs-MacBook-Pro ~ % source /Users/Lorenz_1/Library/r-miniconda/bin/activate
conda activate r-reticulate
(base) Lorenz@Lorenzs-MacBook-Pro ~ % conda activate r-reticulate
(r-reticulate) Lorenz@Lorenzs-MacBook-Pro ~ % /Users/Lorenz_1/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/bin/python "/Users/Lorenz_1/Documents/Uni/7. Semester/Bachelorarbeit/Methodik/Problem solving/Testrun.py"
/Users/Lorenz_1/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dash_bootstrap_components/_table.py:5: UserWarning:
The dash_html_components package is deprecated. Please replace
`import dash_html_components as html` with `from dash import html`
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Lorenz_1/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1349, in do_open
    encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
  File "/Users/Lorenz_1/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1287, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/Users/Lorenz_1/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1333, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Users/Lorenz_1/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1282, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Users/Lorenz_1/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1042, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/Users/Lorenz_1/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 980, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/Users/Lorenz_1/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1440, in connect
    super().connect()
  File "/Users/Lorenz_1/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 952, in connect
    (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/Users/Lorenz_1/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 704, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/Users/Lorenz_1/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 745, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Lorenz_1/Documents/Uni/7. Semester/Bachelorarbeit/Methodik/Problem solving/Testrun.py", line 3, in <module>
    df = pd.read_csv('https://manifestoproject.wzb.eu/down/data/2020b/datasets/MPDataset_MPDS2020b.csv')
  File "/Users/Lorenz_1/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 688, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/Users/Lorenz_1/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 437, in _read
    filepath_or_buffer, encoding, compression
  File "/Users/Lorenz_1/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 183, in get_filepath_or_buffer
    req = urlopen(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "/Users/Lorenz_1/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 137, in urlopen
    return urllib.request.urlopen(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Lorenz_1/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Users/Lorenz_1/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 526, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/Users/Lorenz_1/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 544, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/Users/Lorenz_1/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Users/Lorenz_1/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1392, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "/Users/Lorenz_1/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1351, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known>
(r-reticulate) Lorenz@Lorenzs-MacBook-Pro ~ %
```

Comment: 1. yes, I'm sure what you're asking is possible.  I don't really understand what is, though.  2. provide the *exact code* you have in your buffer (window) when you press 'run in terminal' and it doesn't work.  then we can help :)

Comment: I cannot reproduce: the code you posted runs correctly for me.  I suspect this is a problem with VS.  If you write just that code into a file, save the file, reload visual studio code, and then try to run the file, what happens?

Comment: Strange. I added the complete information from the Terminal, maybe that gives some hints. I also tried via PyCharm, so it's probably not a problem related to VSC.

Comment: Look at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support-py that gives you a "script" to write your code, and a "window" that shows the output when you run each line/cell - just like in R.

Comment: The only difference between your two attempts appears to be that one of them is run in a conda env, whilst the other isn't (at what prompt can you 'type this in and it works?').  In any case this is, sadly, a problem with the environment your end, as the code supplied works fine when you type it in, and when I run it.  beyond that I'm afraid I don't know what's gong on: this will likely get more answers on a support forum for conda (if that's indeed the problem) or the ide (even if two have the same problem).

Comment: Done that @CutePoison! Thanks :) It seems the error occurs in line 3 - which confuses me as there are nor errors when I type it directly into the terminal. The error is still the same (URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known>).

Comment: Updated Homebrew to upgrade Python to 3.9.7., disabled Lulu and it works now!! Don't know what the error was but anyways, it works now. However, I have one more question: I changed the order of the code and put 'd.open_browser()' at the end, but the filters in the two previous lines don't seem to be applied. So, the .csv is still the same (although it should show e.g. just edates > 20140914). Thanks again in advance for your help. (also @CutePoison Jupyter was a great idea, thx!)